# preg_replace wp menu item

Tags: php, wordpress, preg-replace

Need a bit of help with `preg_replace` inside wordpress.

My source code is like this

```
<li id="menu-item-98" class="navigation-heading menu-item menu-item-type-custom menu-item-object-custom menu-item-98">
    <a href="#">Main</a>
</li>
```

By using `preg_replace`, I'd like to change it to the following html markup below whenever the `li` tag has the `navigation-heading` class.

```
<div class="navigation-heading">
<span>
    <span><a href="#">Main</a></span>
</span>
</div>
```

If someone could help me out with my code below, I'd greatly appreciate it.

```
function add_nav_class($output) {
    $output= preg_replace('...', '...', $output, 1);
    return $output;
}
add_filter('wp_nav_menu', 'add_nav_class');
```

Edit:

This is my entire menu (menu ID's can vary in Wordpress).

```
    <ul>
<li class="vendor-dashboard menu-item menu-item-type-custom menu-item-object-custom menu-item-22"><a href="#link">Menu Title</a></li>
<li class="navigation-heading menu-item menu-item-type-custom menu-item-object-custom menu-item-99"><a href="#">WP Heading 1</a></li>
<li class="vendor-dashboard menu-item menu-item-type-custom menu-item-object-custom menu-item-26"><a href="#link">Menu Title</a></li>
<li class="vendor-dashboard menu-item menu-item-type-custom menu-item-object-custom menu-item-16"><a href="#link">Menu Title</a></li>
<li class="navigation-heading menu-item menu-item-type-custom menu-item-object-custom menu-item-44"><a href="#">WP Heading 2</a></li>
</ul>
```

Only the ones with the `navigation-heading` class should be changed to `<div class="navigation-heading">...</div>`

When I used your code, the menu disappeared and only `<div class="navigation-heading">...</div>` was still there.

My ultimate goal, is to create this:

```
<ul>
<div class="navigation-heading"><span><span><a href="#">Heading</a></span></span></div>
<li id="menu-item-56" class="menu-item menu-item-type-custom menu-item-object-custom menu-item-56">
<div class="navigation-heading"><span><span><a href="#">Heading</a></span></span></div>
<li id="menu-item-79" class="menu-item menu-item-type-custom menu-item-object-custom menu-item-79">
<li id="menu-item-80" class="menu-item menu-item-type-custom menu-item-object-custom menu-item-80">
</ul>
```

From the original menu, I can easily remove the `li ID's` (thanks to the website url you shared).

```
function new_submenu_class($menu) { 
    $menu = preg_replace('/id=\"(.*?)\"/', '', $menu );     
    return $menu;  
}
add_filter('wp_nav_menu','new_submenu_class');
```

But from here on out I'm stuck.

**Solution:** (Thanks to **Quixrick**)

```
 function change_link_to_heading($menu) {

    $str = '/<li.*?navigation-heading.*?>\\s*<a href=\"#\">\\s*(.*?)\\s*<\\/a><\\/li>/m';
    $replace = '<div class="navigation-heading"><span><span>$1</span></span></div>';

    $menu = preg_replace($str, $replace, $menu );   

    return $menu;  
}
add_filter('wp_nav_menu','change_link_to_heading');
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This seems relatively straightforward and likely doesn't need to be complex at all.  Basically, you can just capture everything inside the `<li>` tags and then plug that in to your replacement string.

In its simplest form, it'd just be this:

```
<li.*?>(.*?)</li>
```

But if it were me, I'd probably just remove the extra spaces around the match by adding in `\s*` before and after the capture group.

```
<li.*?>\s*(.*?)\s*</li>
```

Well, anyway, once you have your match captured, you can just fill out the text around the `$1` like this:

```
<div class="navigation-heading">\n<span>\n    <span>$1</span>\n</span>\n</div>
```

That should be all you need to kick this thing in the drive.

[Here is a demo of the REGEX](https://regex101.com/r/tS2eG1/1)

[Here is a demo of it in PHP](http://ideone.com/sp9Nev)

Comment: I get the following error when I tried it: `Warning: preg_replace(): Unknown modifier '('`

Comment: My mistake. Now I finally got it! Thank you so much! I'll bookmark the link you've given me.

Comment: I need your guidance again because I stumble on two issues. Updated my post.

Comment: I'm not really certain what you are doing, since the update doesn't really match the first example, but I can take a stab at it.  If you only want to match the ids with the `navigation-heading`, you can just add that into the `<li>` tag matching.  Something like this should do it: `<li.*?navigation-heading.*?>`.  Matching the rest is going to be more of a challenge since you don't have a closing `</li>` like you do in the example.  But you can try matching against the line ending.  [Here's a demo](https://regex101.com/r/tS2eG1/2)

Comment: I'm so sorry; I copied it wrong (it should be with the closing `li` tags). I updated my post. I also created a new demo: https://regex101.com/r/bI1nR7/1 and used your previous answers to get the right expression. The final issue that I have is when I click on _code generator_ and then the `$str` variable.

Answer (score 0):

I recommended using Walker_Nav_Menu class to change html tags around menu elements.

[Check this link with example](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/116708/customizing-walker-nav-menu)

[Source of Walker_Nav_Menu class](https://core.trac.wordpress.org/browser/tags/4.5.2/src//wp-includes/nav-menu-template.php)

Comment: Hmm, I don't really need a new "walker". I was looking for a much simpler solution. ^^;